# <expression> expected got <from> in spring-data hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Working with spring-data and hibernate and trying to write this request in a repository :

```
    @Query("select u from AppUser u inner join u.roles r inner join u.contrats c where r = :role and not exists ( from c.project p where p = :project)")
```

My goal is to get List of AppUser (Users) from entity AppUer ,but with a condition , only those who don't have the entity project .

To explain more , there is an entity Contrat between Project and AppUser  , it contains Project project , AppUser appuser .

There is a mapping between one_to_many between AppUser and Contrat(AppUser can have multiple contrats) .

Also a mapping of one_to_many between Contrat and project ( One project can have multiple contrat ) .

The problme is that this request returns a empty list while it should return a list of 12 users as they don't have the specified project i passe to it.

I remark in this request (from c.project p where p = :project) 'from' is underlined with red line saying  :

```
<expression> expected got <from> in spring-data hibernate.
```

Any idea ?

**Edit**

*Entity AppUser*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String prenom;
    private String nom;
    private Long tel;
    private String cin;
    private String email ;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" )
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="appuser-contrat")
    private Collection<Contrat> contrats = new ArrayList<Contrat>();



    public void addToContrats(Contrat contrat){
        this.contrats.add(contrat);
    }


}
```

*Entity Contrat*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Contrat implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private Date dateDebut ;
        private Date dateFin ;
        private Long idDevloppeur;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_Project")
        @JsonBackReference(value="projet-contrat")
        private Project project;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
        @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-contrat")
        private AppUser appUser;


}
```

*Entity Project*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Project implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String intitule;
        private String description;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project" )
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @JsonManagedReference(value="projet-contrat")
        private Collection<Contrat> contrats  = new ArrayList<Contrat>();



        public void addToContrats(Contrat contrat){
                this.contrats.add(contrat);
        }



 }
```

Comment: maybe  "select p from c.project p ... " ?

Comment: I was following this link http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/09/power-of-hql-condition-on-a-collection/ if you can see it please .

Comment: There is no more the underlined line but always i get an empty list i don't know why

Comment: the missing select isn't the problem (I thought only the last part was your problem sorry). What is in our db ? could it be that the would be selected AppUser entities have no roles or contrats?

Comment: I have edited the post with the tree entities , the 12 users have the right role it's CLIENT , as when i try to list only users with this role i get exactly List of 12 users , the second thing is these users have not any contrats yet , that why im waiting to get all these 12 users , if the user doesnt have any contrat so he doesnt have any field project in contrat , so i should get it in list result .

Comment: that use `left join u.contrats`

Comment: Thank you so much for help , this worked fine for me , can you please explain to me what's the different between both of this types of join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting answer to summarize solution in comments)

In given select query "`inner join u.contrats`" was used, but there were no contracts entities for users. Solution: replace with "`left join u.contrats`".

Inner join vs left join already solved here
[What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)